# Manually rollback the transaction in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I have this code where I'm trying to use a transaction. I want to manually rollback the inserted query if result count is less than 2:

```
$status = false;

try {
  \DB::beginTransaction();

  for($i = 0; $i < count($request->name); $i++) {
    Test::create(['id' => $id,'name' => $request->name[$i]]);

    $results = Questions::where('active', 'yes')->offset($request->number[$i])->limit($request->range[$i])->get(); 

    if($results->count() < 2) {
      $status = true;
    }
      
    foreach($results as $rowresults) {
      User::create(['id' => $id,'name' => $rowresults->name]);
    }
  }

  if($status === false) {
    \DB::commit();
  } else {
    \DB::rollBack(); 
  }
} catch (\PDOException $e) { 
  \DB::rollBack();
}
```

Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: @TimLewis After fetching the `results` there will be insert query, at line no. 4

Comment: Also remember that `rollBack` does not end the execution of the function so `commit` is also ran in your code. It shouldn't matter since the transaction was rolled back but may result in a "no active transaction" type exception. Now the question is, does this code not work? What are the issues?

Comment: @TimLewis I have updated my code can you please check

Comment: Much better, thank you  So what happens with this code currently vs what you're expecting? Using `DB::beginTransaction()`, followed by `Model::create()` then `DB::rollBack()` works as expected for me; the Model is not persisted to the database.

Comment: `Test::create(['id' => $id,'name' => $request->name[$i]]);` -- you are using the same `$id` for all the records you create inside the `for` loop. You should be getting an error when you run this code.

Answer (score -1):

Now your `try catch` can rollback the previous `commit`.

You can check it in `finally` after `catch` and if needed use `\DB::rollBack();`

Comment: Thanks will it rollback my previous insertions after using `\DB::rollBack()` in finally block?

Comment: I tried this  `finally {     if($status===false)   {    \DB::commit();    }   else    {
                \DB::rollBack();  } }` but data is still saved in tables and status is true

Comment: @user3653474 I edited my answer, because the toLevel param is related to the migration. If your code has `commit` in `try` then check in `finally` can't rollBack it. If not, please change your eloquents to db queries, like `DB::table('...')->...`. I didn't see any docs related to this, but maybe this feature doesn't work for eloquent properly.